# Query one column for matches, then return an array of data in the column directly to the left

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I tagged sql in here because apparently the query function uses the same syntax.

[image]

My goal is for:

1. Each data value in column E to individually query column B for matches
2. If there is a match, add it to a array
3. Display the array in column G (next to the corresponding cell)

EX:

If I query column B for "Heavy lifting/straining", the cell in column G will show "Musculoskeletal, Herniation"

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KtC37iZvoY5RWntvMweIuZtIYQhqSnyQHN-jK-w0xaE/edit#gid=2022557090 

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
=JOIN(", "; FILTER(A:A; B:B=E7))
```

---

for partial matches:

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(A:A, REGEXMATCH(B:B, E8)))
```

[image]

Comment: This works for that cell! But not for the ones with multiple risk factors (ie, "Cord compression" which has "cancer, IVDU" as risk factors